# "Cross-origin-request blocked". How to overcome that?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When I am calling rest services using ionic and angularJS It's getting "Cross-origin-request blocked". How to overcome that?

Thank you.

Better to Add https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en to your chrome extension.

Comment: may i know my answers is working for u?

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*">
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/javascript">
```

You will set above text on your server page that means which page you want access from remote. And one more thing i am using coldfusion server so above code looks in cf code format. So you will change syntax which server you have use.

Answer (score 0):

A cross-origin request is a request from one domain to another. For security purposes you cannot get around that unless you control the server of the receiving domain. To solve your issue you must, therefore, make the request from and to the same domain. For more information, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass them in certain web browsers.

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Chrome has been most successful for me.